# Can't get text data from the PDF file on the web

Tags: python

I'm working on getting 'text' data from the PDF file on the web. But I couldn't.

sample: https://otd.harvard.edu/upload/files/OTD_Startup_Guide.pdf

1. use `requests`

The code:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://otd.harvard.edu/upload/files/OTD_Startup_Guide.pdf')
print(r.content)
```

Can get data but it was not 'text'. It's encrypted.

> Adobe InDesign 7.0\n                  /;/metadata\n               \n               \n                  saved\n                  xmp.iid:63935542733768118A6DE4CA3B065193\n                  2011-08-16T10:14:49-04:00\n                  Adobe InDesign 7.0\n                  /;/metadata\n               \n               \n

2. use `pyPDF2`
   Successfully get data if PDF is on the same directory. But if it's on the web, I had this error.

The error:

> webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

```py
import PyPDF2
import webbrowser

with webbrowser.get("https://otd.harvard.edu/upload/files/OTD_Startup_Guide.pdf") as f:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
    page = reader.getPage(0)
    print(page.extractText())
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you believe the content of the PDF you downloaded using `requests` is encrypted? The PDF at the link you provided isn't encrypted.

Comment: This is not encrypted, it just looks like some encoding. Unicode for example. I'm sure, a pdf parser can handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pdf file is not directly readable by requests module. What it fetches is the bytes. You will have to save the file locally and then read it with something like pyPDF2 or pdfminer.

```py
localpath = "./downloaded_file.pdf"

import requests
def download_file(url, localpath):
    with open(localpath, "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

Now pass the localpath to pyPDF

```py
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(localpath)
page = reader.getPage(0)
print(page.extractText())
```